# Sketch a line in NetLogo From it's coefficents

Tags: netlogo

How can a draw a line in NetLogo given in the following form:

```
                                    Ax+By+C=0
```

That is, **A** , **B** and **C** are given.

**CODE:**

```js
    to make-line[a]; a is list containing A, B and C and in that order.
    let x 0
    let y((-item 2 A) / item 1 A)
    let y1 0
    let x1((-item 2 A) / item 0 A)
    crt 1[
      set size 0.5 setxy x y
      pen-down
      facexy x1 y1
      while [distancexy x1 y1 > 0.5]
          [
           fd 0.1
          ]
         ]
     end
```

**PROBLEM:**
The points tend to be outside the NetLogo boundaries many a lines.

*Given the coefficients of a line, is there a way to draw one using any extensions or library functions directly*

Comment: Solving this involves doing a bunch of grungy math I doubt you'll be able to convince anyone else to do for you for free (though it doesn't hurt to try!).