# Line computed in turtle's direction doesn't match shape heading

Tags: netlogo

**Code:**

;Call check in the code below

```
 to-report calculate-line[x y angle]
      let m tan angle
      let A m 
      let B -1 
      let C (- m * x + y) 
      report (list A B C)
    end

    to make-line[a]; a is list containing A, B and C and in that order.
      let x 0
      let y((- item 2 a) / item 1 a)
      let y1 0
      let x1((- item 2 a) / item 0 a)
      hatch 1[
        set size 0.15 setxy x y
        pendown
        facexy x1 y1

            fd 7   
      ]
    end

    to check
      clear-all
      crt 1[
        set size 2
        set shape "arrow"
        setxy -3 3
        set heading 268
        make-line calculate-line xcor ycor heading-to-angle heading
        ]
    end
to-report heading-to-angle [ h ]
  report (90 - h) mod 360
end
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Question:**

Why isn't the arrow heading and line in the same direction? I just compute a line from the coordinates of the turtle and heading and plot it. Am I missing some approximation happening in btw the code?

Comment: Why are x and y1 always 0? Offhand, that doesn't look right.

Comment: @SethTisue It finds the points which intersect the x axis and y axis.  Please suggest corrections to the code you think are correct.

Comment: I think you should debug this yourself.

Comment: @SethTisue Thanks the reply. The problem is with `make-line` procedure. I can't figure out a way to sketch a line in NetLogo given it is in form `Ax+By+C=0`.

Comment: Consider some example values of A, B, and C. Work out the solution on paper and verify it is correct. Then run those same values through your code, line by line, and see where your code diverges from your pen and paper calculations. If you aren't able to work this problem correctly with pen and paper, you probably aren't going to be able to write code to do it, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine if you have the arrow centred at (0,0). See this version of the check procedure from your code:

```
to check
  clear-all
  crt 1
  [ set size 2
    set shape "arrow"
    setxy 0 0
    set heading random 360
    make-line calculate-line xcor ycor heading
  ]
end
```

But if you change the`setxy 0 0` to other locations (such as `setxy 3 2`) the whole thing separates. This suggests that there is no approximation, the problem is your calculation of the line coordinates. Probably in your calculation of the list of A, B and C, but I can't actually work out what they are supposed to be and the variable names are no help.

Comment: I am basically computing the line coefficients in  $Ax+By+C=0$, given a point $x_0,y_0$ and angle the line makes with positive y direction.

Comment: In that case, one problem may be that you are taking the tan of the wrong angle. A turtle's heading is angle relative to the vertical (so 0 is to top of world). If you are using the equation of a line, then the angle you care about is relative to the horizontal (to the right of the world). Regardless, it is a trigonometry problem, not a NetLogo problem, so you need to post the equations that you are using and not just the code. Also, is the line supposed to start at the arrow, or just be parallel to it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, that was a stupid error. But still show erroneous results in some cases. Please changed code above.

Comment: You need to do some trigonometry and mathematics on paper. Work through the equations with different headings (at least try it with 60, 120, 240 and 300 so you get each quadrant) and work out what you actually want the code to do. Your problem is logic, not coding and I can't provide any assistance unless you provide some equations.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I wish to write a code that given a equation $Ax+By+C=0$, sketches the line in NetLogo.

Comment: starting from what point? Your equation simply does the line, it doesn't say where it starts and stops

Comment: It should start and end at the world maximum coordinates, considering no wrapping is permitted.

Comment: Please start a different question if you are now asking about code to draw a line

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632521/sketch-a-line-in-netlogo-from-its-coefficents